# How to correctly use multiple initialization functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to understand whether or not the concept behind using multiple initialization functions is bad practice. By an *initialization function* I mean either of the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    //... some code here
}

(function(){
    //.... some code here
})();
```

Time and time again I have seen *multiple initialization functions* being used and I always thought that this is ultimately a bad practice, but am I really wrong?

Based on that, would anyone care to enlighten me as to whether is it a good or bad practice to use *multiple initialization functions*?

**Edit**: removed irrelevant example of a bad use of closure and encapsulation.

Comment: your  function declaration is not accessible outside the scope of the IIFE you wrapped it in

Comment: @charlietfl that is true, however my question goes beyond that fact, care to elaborate based on my question statement?

Comment: Beyond that I'm not really clear on what you are asking. Not clear what *"multiple initialization functions"* means

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by the term "*multiple initialization function*".

Comment: @charlietfl Initialization function: the only way I could think of naming a `$(document).ready` or a `(function(){})()` function

Comment: Those are accomplishing two completely different things. The first is a jQuery wrapper that runs when your DOM is loaded. The latter is simply an IIFE. It runs (self-executes) immediately and doesn't wait for anything.

Comment: @Antiga that is true, however is it good or bad practice to use them together? If it is not a problem, then as you can see in my example (a bad usage) how can they be used properly together. I just see them being used together and multiple of them but I never understood whether or not this was a bad practice, or the purpose of having multiple when one might be all that is needed. That is what I am looking to understand

Comment: I don't understand why you think using two completely unrelated patterns, that have nothing to do with one another, and have no real overlap in function, would be "bad practice?" The short answer is "no." You're fine. Use them both.

Comment: *"see them used together"* .... what is *them"*?. Can use document.ready more than once

Comment: @charlietfl I understand that I **can** use them together, I am trying to understand whether or not it is a good or bad practice, that is all.

Comment: It's not a bad practice, you are just not using them correctly. If you want your code to be isolated from other code you wrap it up in an anonymous function (when should this function be called is a different story). Clearly, your code shouldn't be isolated if they need each other.

Comment: Lots of instances where they can't be avoided such as needing different script combinations on different pages. There is no real performance issues if that's what you are asking

Comment: @MinusFour that makes sense to me, having multiple said functions is of course possible, but it not being a bad practice is a good thing to know, as I have always been against it for reasons I could simply not grasp.

Comment: @charlietfl that's interesting, do you mind elaborating on these instances?

Comment: Thanks for the accepted answer. I would suggest updating your question to get rid of the scoping error, as it is (fairly or unfairly) distracting readers from the actual question you're asking. It's a good question and could benefit others if it could be cleaned up.

Comment: @AshwinBalamohan I agree, good idea bad example

Comment: Perfect example would be  the millions of wordpress sites out there that have all sorts of different widgets installed in back end admin. All those widgets come from different sources and have to be able to perform regardless of what other scripts are in page

Comment: @charlietfl great example, that pretty much illustrates when it is a good practice vs bad, the bad would be poor code organization (thanks to the accepted answer below).

Comment: But that example isn't bad practice per-se ... it's environment related. Not all sites or apps are created all in one project. Also not all parts of a site need to have interdependence

Comment: @charlietfl well that simply goes more to my point, what **is** good vs bad practice in terms of using initialization functions? The weird thing is that I don't find anything regarding the proper vs improper use of said functions (IIFE and JQuery wrapper)  in the docs... or perhaps I have not yet stumbled into it.

Comment: You won't find anything like that in library docs. Look for different style guides instead. For example http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/

Comment: @charlietfl will do, thanks for sticking around!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct in that it's generally a good idea to organize code when you can.

Centralizing initialization functions makes it easier for another developer to figure out which statements are being executed at any given time. This facilitates debugging and becomes increasingly important when multiple developers are working on the same code.

Perhaps consider doing something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function findLionelRichie() {
        console.log('found Lionel Richie');
    }

    function findWhomeverElseNeedsFinding() {
        console.log('found all the others');
    }       

    (function initialize() {
        findLionelRichie();
        findWhomeverElseNeedsFinding();
    })();
});
```

That being said, they cannot always be avoided (for example, when calling functions from external libraries). Try to keep it as organized as you can on your end, however.

Comment: So in your opinion, it simply comes down to code organization rather than it being a pure negative coding practice. That is quite reassuring given that my gut always tells me to stray away from using multiple of said functions. I guess there is a time and place to use them, but in general it's better not to, would that be right?

Comment: Bang on. Your instincts are correct. 

JavaScript does not impose any rigorous sort of code structure (unlike a language like Java, for example), so it's a good idea to try and keep it as organized as you can. JavaScript code can also execute asynchronously, making poorly-organized code a nightmare to trace through.

Comment: I edited my question to remove the example, feel free to modify yours if you think it would be fit to do so... and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Creating a function within another function changes the scope of the function in the same way it would change the scope of a variable.

The functions defined within another function won't be accessible outside the function unless they have been attached to an object that is accessible outside the function:

Comment: That is true thanks to the concept of closures, just keep in mind that is a code example which is meant to fail in order to illustrate my point, is it good or bad practice to use more than one initialization function